# Why was my question about Hydra closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I just saw that [one of my questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/87080/42981) were put on hold (and downvoted without comment) as off-topic. My impression was that there are also pentesting issues discussed here. As such, my question is about a technical issue related to pentesting.

I just reviewed the Tour page and the Help Center - "What topics can I ask about here?".  Penetration testing is listed there as legitimate topic, and I think that is not restricted just philosophical aspects of pentesting.  However, if technicalities of pentesting are out of scope, then this should be stated there.  Until then I request the unwarranted ban on my question to be lifted.

Comment: What, even a discussion on a community decision gets downvoted? What is this here?!

Answer (score 6):

There is no ban on your question - it has just been closed by 5 members of the community, and my quick review agrees with them. That question is definitely off topic here. It is not a question about security. It is not even a question about penetration testing.

It is a question you could possibly pose to the Hydra team to ask them why Hydra has that functionality, but we don't know why they have it set up like that nor what recommendations they would make.

Comment: @countermode to clarify: that is not a question about pentesting, it is a question about the hydra tool. Same as we wouldnt want a question on command line flags for some other tool... a question that is actually about pentesting is ABSOLUTELY ontopic here.

Comment: So questions on pentesting tools are out of scope?

Comment: No - you'll see we have many questions that are about pen testing tools, however there is a distinction between questions that are security questions, and those that are really only appropriate on the vendor's own forums. Just having a question mention a security tool does not make it on topic.

Comment: @countermode questions about configuration or tweaks to specific programs are out of scope - regardless if that tool could be used for pentesting purposes.